# Question about directions and particles

Tags: meaning, video-games

I'm playing a Japanese video game and am having a small problem understanding the configuration instructions for my controller. These two sentences in particular:

左スティック上方向で前に移動

左スティック右方向で右に移動

I understand those sentences when broken down, for example the first is "left stick", "upward" and "move forward" (I think), would that mean "Move your left stick forward and up"? I feel like the particles are tripping me up in both sentences so thought I'd ask what others thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like で is what's causing trouble for you. One of the functions of で is to mark how something happens, similar to "by means of."

> 左スティック上方向で by means of left stick up orientation
> 前に移動 forward movement
>
> 左スティック右方向で by means of left stick right orientation
> 右に移動 movement to right

The equivalent boiled down English expressions might be:
"left stick up to move forward"
"left stick right to move right"